# WebApi throws 403 error always even whith CORS enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi developed in .NET Core 2.0 for my backend. When I test my production build, I can't call a method from my controller, I've activated cors to allow everything just for testing purpose. When I build my WebApi for Development environment it works perfectly fine.

This is what I have in my startup class

```
public void ConfigureProduction(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        //var options = new RewriteOptions()
        //    .AddRedirectToHttps();

        //app.UseRewriter(options);

        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseCors(builder => {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to access a method from your project and it is throwing 403 error or you're trying to access some other API from your project and which is throwing 403? Also if it is a 3rd party API, can you check the environment variables / keys etc?

Comment: I'm trying to access to my API from an angular 5 application hosted in the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally you need to allow credentials:

- [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests)

  ```
  app.UseCors(builder =>
  {
      builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
      builder.AllowAnyMethod();
      builder.AllowAnyHeader();
      builder.AllowCredentials(); // <-- add this line
  });
  ```
- [Client](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions)

  ```
  let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({withCredentials: true});
  ```

Comment: I'll try this when i get home, but why is this happening only in Production mode?

Comment: @Juanma are there other configurations in the development mode?

Comment: Nope, it's only a blank webapi c# template. The configs are the defaults when the template is generated